# Java, android WebView

Tags: java, android

I have built a WebView application in java.
Basically what i did was Created a WebView loaded a url, but what happened is when i click on the Uri tel:, the app crashes i have no idea what to do.
I have tried to override the Web. I did override WebViewClient.
App always crashing if uri = tel something by this code:

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("html5rocks.com")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code where you are using Uri tel: ?

Comment: Malwinder, basically the website got some phones and basically all of them are tel:, and when i click them it just crashes the app for some unknown reason

Comment: Ok. Can you post the exception?

Comment: I am currently not at home to actually show you the exception, but you have any idea why would it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
```

You need `ACTION_DIAL` and not `ACTION_VIEW`.